clangd cannot find iostream
i use mason-lspconfig, mason and neovim-lspconfig but
Clangd cannot find iostream... i do have a compile_commands.json generated by cmake and ninja
Image:
editor
Github Link
the code or the tutorial is from:
typecraft dev
i added the "--query-driver", "path to my msys2 mingw 64" from clangd.llvm.org
but still did not managed to get it working

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
